# How to represent terrain as physics objects in Box2D/Farseer

Tags: box2d, farseer

What's the best way to represent generated 2D terrain in Box2D/Farseer?
The terrain consists of some hills - think of some dunes.

There is a method to generate polygons from a texture described in the Farseer documentation:
http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/documentation (Section "Texture to polygon")

But actually I don't need the terrain as polygon. I only need the surface-line.
Representing the terrain via polynomials would be great but I couldn't find any support for polynomials in Box2D/Farseer.

Do I have to work with Edges and LineArcs to model my dunes, or is there anything that would fit better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emanuele Feronato provides a tutorial for exactly what I was looking for on his blog:

[Create a terrain like the one in Tiny Wings with Flash and Box2D](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2011/07/14/create-a-terrain-like-the-one-in-tiny-wings-with-flash-and-box2d/)